# How to enable access to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to serve a Static Websites utilyzing a S3 Bucket.
Unfortunately, a 403 error and an Access Denied message is being shown.
You can check it with the following endpoint:

http://sosanimalesco.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Details:

My objects are public.

I've tryied Access Point Policy as:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But it throws a 'Unsupported Resource ARN In Policy: The resource ARN is not supported for the resource-based policy attached to resource type S3 Access Point.' error.

How to enable access to S3 bucket?